# startActivity() first remove the fragment and only then moves to another Activity

Tags: android

I have an Activity with a fragment in front. now when i use StartActivity() the fragment is first removed and you can see for a half a sec the Ui of the activity before it moves to the next Activity...
any idea how to keep the fragment in the front until the last moment before switching to the next Activity?

Thanks

Comment: Fragments are not removed when you start another activity. Who is removing the fragment?

Comment: show your code where you are starting activity.